# HTML5 Service Workers: Life Cycle, Persistence, and Code Loading

Tags: html, service-worker

I want my web app to occasionally show a notification on the user's desktop. GMail and Facebook use this same technique.

Using the HTML5 Notification API to obtain the user's permission and subsequently show a notification is very well documented and straightforward. But in my case I'd like to show these notifications to the user if even he isn't browsing my site. My research points me to the Service Worker API. I've run through some Service Worker tutorials and although I comprehend most of the content, I am left with the following questions:

(1) I understand the Download=>Install=>Activate cycle but I can't get a sense of exactly when a previously installed Service Worker thread is launched or shutdown. The only relevant quote I've found says that the thread "can be started and shutdown at any time." That was an old article though. Do we know more now? Specifically: Is the thread started when the user boots up his computer? Or is it started when the user opens his browser for the first time after boot? etc... Similarly, when is the thread shutdown? Could it conceivably stay shutdown for minutes? hours? days?

(2) How do I persist a value? Without getting into specifics, there's a single 32-bit value I'll need to persist on the user's computer after showing a notification. That's the extent of my required "state" information. But for reasons unknown, articles indicate that localStorage is not available via a Service Worker context. How then shall I store this value?

(3) My Service Worker code will depend on another object I created which lives in 'utils.js.' How do I load that into memory so my Service Worker can see it? With my web app, I can do this using a `<script>` tag in the HTML. But in this case, there's no HTML -- only JavaScript. So how do I tell the the Service Worker to load this code into memory?

(4) How do I debug my Service Worker? With a standard web app I can hit Alt-Cmd-I in Chrome to open the debugging panel. But in this case, I'm not debugging a specific site -- I'm debugging a Service Worker thread.

Thanks,

Festus

Comment: Was a Service Worker API designed to persists browser sessions? I am just curious if you browsed to another site outside of your domain how would your service workers fire post backs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The service worker thread is not going to be executed again until some event occurs. In your case, you want your service worker to be executed when the `push` event occurs, that is when your server sends a notification to the client.
2. You can use IndexedDB ([localForage](https://github.com/mozilla/localForage) is a simple library on top of IndexedDB that implements an interface similar to localStorage).
3. [importScripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/importScripts).
4. Developer tools are still being worked on in Firefox (you can use about:serviceworkers and about:debugging in some versions of Firefox), in Chrome you can see service workers in the developer panel between the sources and in the resources tab (you can also emulate a push event from there): https://www.chromium.org/blink/serviceworker/service-worker-faq

There are a few examples of usage of the Web Push API on the [ServiceWorker Cookbook](https://serviceworke.rs/).